# Constructing a proper skew field

Tags: abstract-algebra

A problem asks to construct (using 2 x 2 matrices over the integer ring) a proper skew field, and then find the inverse of a general element of the field.

The definition of a proper skew field is given here as:

> A proper skew field (F,+,.) (|F| must be infinite by a theorem of Wedderburn) is an algebraic
>   structure that satisfies all the axioms of a field except that multiplication is not always
>   commutative).

I am not quite sure what that means, but I am guessing that in this case, a proper skew field is just "a bunch of" 2 by 2 matrices with integer elements that can only be added or multiplied. And I know that matrix multiplication is not always commutative.

So when asked to construct such a field, do I just make a random 2 by 2 matrix with integer elements?

I am also then not sure on what it means to find the inverse of a general element in the proper skew field. Is the meaning of inverse here not meaning just to find the general form of the inverse of the 2 by 2 matrix?

Comment: You are apparently asked to find a certain collection of $2\times2$ integer matrices which together form a skew field (using standard addition, multiplication and inverse). You have to be clever with which matrices you include in your set as not all matrices are invertible, and especially the sum of invertible matrices need not be invertible.

Comment: @Arthur, Oh I see, but I am still not sure about, find the inverse of a general element of the field part. Do I just write down the general formula we use to find the inverse of a 2 by 2, and since this is the integer ring there isn't anything that i should note except the usual that the determinant must not be zero.

Comment: The determinant must be $\pm1$, actually. Otherwise the inverse isn't an integer matrix, and thus the original matrix isn't considered invertible in this context.

Comment: @Arthur, Thank you very much I understand it now.